# Find the extreme points of the unit ball of $L^1[0, 1], L^p[0, 1], L^{\infty}[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

I understand the definition but am having some trouble thinking about exactly what those points (what types of functions they are).
I've seen the correspondent answers for $l^n(\mathbb{N})$ but are there any connections on the extreme points?

Answer (score 0):

For a start, candidates for extreme points are functions with norm equal to one.

1. Case $L^1[0,1]$: here one can show that no extreme points exist, because every function with norm one can be written as sum of two functions with disjoint support and norm $1/2$.
2. Case $L^p$, $1<p<\infty$: here the norm is strict convex. Hence convex combinations of function with norm equal to one have norm....
3. Case $L^\infty$: every function with norm one is an extreme point.

You still have to fill in the details. Hope this helps.